# Define type for fileinput.input file object

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to find & replace in file using below code snippet:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import fileinput
import re

TEXT_FILE_PATH = Path.cwd() / "temp.txt"
FIND_PUBLIC_PATH_REGEX = r"(publicPath: ').*(',)"
REPLACE_PUBLIC_PATH_REGEX = r"\1/\2"

with fileinput.input(TEXT_FILE_PATH, inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(re.sub(FIND_PUBLIC_PATH_REGEX, REPLACE_PUBLIC_PATH_REGEX, line), end="")
```

The problem is I am getting type error on last line which says:

```
No overloads for "sub" match the provided arguments
Argument types: (Literal['(publicPath: \').*(\',)'], Literal['\\1/\\2'], AnyStr@input)Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

I can't understand why I am getting this error.

Regards.

Comment: This isn't really a Python error - this is just your linter Pylance trying to be helpful. If your code works, you could probably ignore this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I resolve this warning/error then?

Comment: maybe try converting the regex strings to actual regex objects? Like `MY_REGEX = re.compile(r"\1/\2")`

Comment: The problem is the same just a different type this time. `Argument types: (Pattern[str], Pattern[str], AnyStr@input)`. However, if I cast a line in the last line to `str(line)` error goes away. But I don't want to add this kind of patch. I want a pythonic way.

Comment: "Pythonic" doesn't apply.  It's not Python that's complaining.  It's an add-on package, and it's clearly wrong.  The Pythonic way is to ignore the warning.  There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Should I raise the issue in VSCode pylance or mypy then?